# How to bind WPF LiveCharts(LVC) enable drill down view?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, data-binding, livecharts

I am currently learning WPF and venturing [WPF LiveCharts(LVC)](https://lvcharts.net/). I understand that the chart has a [`Chart.DataClick`](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Events) event which could be bound to a point in Chart. However i am unable to get the event to populate a new chart (replacing the old chart) based on the point clicked, which should basically give me a drill down view of the clicked point.

I referred to this [example](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Doughnut%20Chart) however I am not sure how to bind the new series collection based on the clicked point and bind it to my chart.

Theoretically I thought of the following steps,

1. User clicks on a point and the code behind checks the point name and
   gets a new predefined seriescollection property
2. The chart which was already populated based on datacontext and Series, in XAML, is replaced by the new bindingsource seriescollection2 property in the same class.

Here I'm a little confused as I am unsure of how to MVVM the series collection with the chart as the [example i am working on](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Doughnut%20Chart) does not seem to have implemented MVVM.

I read about [`IObservableChartPoint`](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Observable%20Point) the documentation and have a notion that this may be the key to achieve i am looking for. It is strange that no one has posted anything about implementing this library to achieve the drilldown view.

How I would like to use the chart is by reading a flat file with series points data and plot them in a Donut or a Column Chart. I am posting the code that I could write to achieve what I want.

Code Behind:

```
Public ReadOnly Property SeriesCOllection2 As SeriesCollection
    Get
        _SeriesCollection2 = New SeriesCollection From {
            New PieSeries With {
                .Title = "Page1",
                .Values = New ChartValues(Of ObservableValue) From {
                    New ObservableValue(8)
                },
                .DataLabels = True
            },
            New PieSeries With {
                .Title = "Pag2",
                .Values = New ChartValues(Of ObservableValue) From {
                    New ObservableValue(6)
                },
                .DataLabels = True
            },
            New PieSeries With {
                .Title = "Pag3",
                .Values = New ChartValues(Of ObservableValue) From {
                    New ObservableValue(10)
                },
                .DataLabels = True
            },
            New PieSeries With {
                .Title = "Pag4",
                .Values = New ChartValues(Of ObservableValue) From {
                    New ObservableValue(4)
                },
                .DataLabels = True
            },
              New PieSeries With {
                .Title = "Pag5",
                .Values = New ChartValues(Of ObservableValue) From {
                    New ObservableValue(4)
                },
                .DataLabels = True
            }
        }
        Return _SeriesCOllection2
    End Get

End Property>
```

Code Behind Events:

```
Private _SeriesCOllection2 As SeriesCollection
Public Property SeriesCollection As SeriesCollection

Private Sub Chart_DataClick(sender As Object, chartPoint As ChartPoint) ' Click event on chart data point
    If chartPoint.SeriesView.Title.ToLower.Equals("opera") Then
        Chart.Series = _SeriesCOllection2
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) ' Reset the chart
    Chart.Series = SeriesCollection
End Sub
```

Chart XAML:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:BasicChart}"     
<lvc:PieChart
                Name="Chart"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="0,15"
                DataClick="Chart_DataClick"
                InnerRadius="80"
                Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}">

                <lvc:PieChart.DataTooltip>
                    <lvc:DefaultTooltip SelectionMode="OnlySender" />
                </lvc:PieChart.DataTooltip>

            </lvc:PieChart>
```

Does anyone have any idea around this or point me in the right direction? A little code walkthrough would also be appreciated in case of a solution.

PS: I am using WPF vb.net.

Comment: Show your [mcve] and make sure you ask a specific question. This feels more like something that can be answered by a tutorial, and SO is not great for that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, posted the sample code. Let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: That _really_ isn't your [mcve]. It's just copied from that tutorial, right? It is unclear what your actual question is. What problem have you found with this code? BTW, no one is going to do a "walkthrough" with you because, well, this isn't what SO is for. I _think_ you are asking how to bind your view and controller in this specific case, but, honestly, I don't think anyone is going to read through this tutorial code to figure it out. Maybe you could take the tutorial and write your own example that demonstrates the problem?